# Play Framework: How to serialize/deserialize an enumeration to/from JSON

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following enumeration...

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {

  type MyEnum = Value

  val Val1 = Value("val1")
  val Val2 = Value("val2")
  val ValN = Value("valN")

  implicit val myEnumFormat = new Format[MyEnum] {
    def reads(json: JsValue) = MyEnum.withName(json.as[String].value) // doesn't compile
    def writes(myEnum: MyEnum) = JsString(myEnum.toString)
  }
}
```

... I need to serialize/deserialize it to/from JSON. `myEnumFormat` does not compile and I always get the following error message:

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : models.MyEnum.Value
[error]  required: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[models.MyEnumValue]
[error]  Note: implicit value myEnumFormat is not applicable here because it comes after the application point and it lacks an explicit result type
[error]     def reads(json: JsValue) = MyEnum.withName(json.as[JsString].value)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try changing it to

```
def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(MyEnum.withName(json.as[String].value))
```

Comment: It is not a good approach. If json is JsNull, ```json.as[String]```will throw an exception.

Answer (score 34):

`implicit val genderReads = Reads.enumNameReads(Gender)` is working fine for me. Play Scala 2.4.2

Answer (score 15):

Expanding on @surenyonjan's response, the following works nicely with Play Json 2.6:

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnum = Value
  val e1, e2 = Value

  implicit val myEnumReads = Reads.enumNameReads(MyEnum)
  implicit val myEnumWrites = Writes.enumNameWrites
}
```

Answer (score 14):

## Play 2.7+

Since play-json 2.7 there is a [`Json.formatEnum`](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/master/play-json/shared/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Json.scala#L262) method. Added in scope of [#140](https://github.com/playframework/play-json/pull/140)

*Example:*

```
object MyEnum extends Enumeration {
  type MyEnum = Value

  val Val1 = Value("val1")
  val Val2 = Value("val2")
  val ValN = Value("valN")

  implicit val format: Format[MyEnum] = Json.formatEnum(this)
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer now.

Answer (score 3):

I have put together more generic and re-usable EnumerationReads, EnumerationWrites and EnumerationFormat classes and have posted them on my github page:

[EnumerationCombinators.scala](https://github.com/srushingiv/org.skrushingiv/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/skrushingiv/json/EnumerationCombinators.scala)