# Error in converting class with enum attribute to Json with Play 2.3 and Scala 2.11.1

Tags: json, scala, enums, playframework-2.3, play-json

i have a case class `User` with an `Enum` as one of its attributes

i want to convert this class into `Json` using `Play-Json` api but i am getting error
here is my User class

```
case class User ( name : String= "", id : String = "", status : UserStatus = ACTIVE)

object User{

implicit val userFmt = Json.format[User]

}
```

UserStatus

```
 object UserStatus extends Enumeration {
    type  UserStatus = Value
         val ACTIVE , INACTIVE , BLOCKED , DELETED = Value

         implicit val statusFmt = Json.format[UserStatus]  
  }
```

it gives me following error in User class

> No implicit format for UserStatus available

on this line

```
implicit val userFmt = Json.format[User]
```

and following error in UserStatus(enum)

> No unapply function found

on this line

```
implicit val statusFmt = Json.format[UserStatus]
```

please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only needed a formatter for your enum. I have rewritten your example using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816753/play-framework-how-to-serialize-deserialize-an-enumeration-to-from-json) as a way to write the formatter:

```
  import play.api.libs.json._
    object UserStatus extends Enumeration {
      type  UserStatus = Value
      val ACTIVE , INACTIVE , BLOCKED , DELETED = Value
    }



    case class User ( name : String= "", id : String = "", status : UserStatus.UserStatus = UserStatus.ACTIVE)

    object User{
      implicit val myEnumFormat = new Format[UserStatus.UserStatus] {
        def reads(json: JsValue) = JsSuccess(UserStatus.withName(json.as[String]))
        def writes(myEnum: UserStatus.UserStatus) = JsString(myEnum.toString)
      }

      implicit val userFmt = Json.format[User]

    }

    println(Json.toJson(User("1", "2", UserStatus.ACTIVE)))
```

Comment: is there any way to  add a formatter in parent class and use it in the child classes as well , plus if i have a trait and 4 5 child classes how can i ensure code reusability for these formatters?

Comment: I tried to use traits to store the formatters some time ago, and at the end it becomes messy. Currently I declare them in objects. And whenever you need the formatters of an object in another, you can just import them at the beginning of the object. What do you think?