# Using case class to parse data containing enum in ScalikeJdbc and ScalaJson

Tags: scala, playframework, enums, scalikejdbc

I need to read certain **enum values** (apart from other regular stuff, including some *optionally null* values) from `MySQL` database in `Scala`. I'm using `ScalikeJdbc` for querying `MySQL` and parsing the result-set. I cannot find any mention of *parsing enum types* in [it's docs](http://scalikejdbc.org/) (maybe I need to dig deeper).

But my target application needs to have both ways of loading data: database and `JSON` files. Therefore I'm also using [`ScalaJson`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson) (`Play Framework`) to parse Json files for reading exactly the same data as I would from `MySQL` database.

I'm aware that both `ScalikeJdbc` and `ScalaJson` support parsing data by using `Scala`'s **case class**es for *automatic conversion*.

---

My questions are:

- Does `ScalikeJdbc` support parsing *Enum values* [like `ScalaJson`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23816753/play-framework-how-to-serialize-deserialize-an-enumeration-to-from-json)?
- Can the same `case class` be used for parsing data in both `ScalikeJdbc` and `ScalaJson` or do they need to be different? My `case class` in question would contain parameters of custom types, which in turn are `case class`es themselves. These `case class`es accept parameters of following types apart from *Enum values* (basically, they don't contain parameter of exactly same types, but the *level of complexity* would be identical):

  - `Int`, `String`
  - `Option[Int]`, `Option[String]`
  - `Option[Seq[ (Int, String, Option[Int], Option[String]) ]]`
- *Enums* can be totally done away with by adding *extra manual validation*, although the end result might not be nearly as *neat*. That said, in general, is it a good idea to use *Enums* at all (particularly when reading data from database or `JSON` / `XML` files) or *overhead of adding enums* is too much to justify their benefits?

Comment: While I did away with `Enums` in my `case class`es, I still need to use the same `case class`es for both `ScalikeJdbc` and `ScalaJson`; The `companion object` of those `case class`es must extend `SQLSyntaxSupport[T]` (as per `ScalikeJdbc`); which creates **ambiguous reference error** when I add the `Json` `reads[T]`, `writes[T]` etc methods in them

Comment: Although I've described how I achieved utilizing the same `case class`es for both `ScalikeJdbc` and `ScalaJson`, parsing `Enums` using `ScalikeJdbc` (and mapping them to `Enum` defined in `Scala` code) is still an open question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As told in comment on the question, I did away with reading `Enums` directly from `MySQL` database or `JSON`. Obviously, those fields are now simple `VARCHAR`s in the database and I moved the validation logic into my `Scala` code. Since I'm performing validation separately, the `case class`es that I'm using to hold data read from `MySQL` or `JSON` no longer have any `Enum.Value` type fields.

I would say that it would've made a lot more sense to have `Enums` directly in the database; but in lack of simple solution, I chose this workaround. It is still an open question and I will update the answer once I find the solution.

---

Coming to the other part of my question

> Can the same case class be used for parsing data in both ScalikeJdbc
>   and ScalaJson or do they need to be different?

**Yes**

I created `case class`es with `companion object`s and I'm able to use them for *automatic-conversion* in both `ScalikeJdbc` as well as `ScalaJson`. I'm posting a complete `case class` along with it's `companion object` that serves this *dual purpose*.

*Note*: This code sample comes from a *framework* that aims to *move* `MySQL` tables from one-location to another. *[**actual production-code**]*

Case-class:

```
case class Table(dbId: Option[Int] = None,
                 id: Option[Int] = None,
                 name: String,
                 shouldCopy: Option[Boolean] = None,
                 lastUpdated: Option[DateTime] = None
                )
```

Companion-object:

```
object Table {

  private def mapResultToTable(rs: WrappedResultSet): Table = Table(
    dbId = rs.intOpt("db_id"),
    id = rs.intOpt("id"),
    name = rs.string("name"),
    shouldCopy = rs.booleanOpt("should_copy"),
    lastUpdated = rs.dateTimeOpt("last_updated").flatMap { zonedDateTime: ZonedDateTime =>
      Some(DateTime.parse(zonedDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)).plusMinutes(330))
    }
  )

  def getTables(db: Db)(implicit session: DBSession): Seq[Table] = {
    sql"""
       SELECT
         *
       FROM
         db_name.tables
       WHERE
         db_id = ${db.id} AND
         should_copy = b'1'
       ORDER BY
         name ASC
    """.
      map(mapResultToTable).
      list().
      apply()
  }

  // for Play-Json [Scala-Json]
  implicit val dateTimeJsReader = JodaReads.jodaDateReads("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
  implicit val dateTimeWriter = JodaWrites.jodaDateWrites("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")

  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Table]
  implicit val writes = Json.writes[Table]
}
```

Here's explanation for specific parts of the code:

- `def mapResultToTable(rs: WrappedResultSet)`

  This method reads the *result-set* of database query and builds an `object` of the `case class`
- `def getTables(db: Db)`

  This method queries `MySQL` database is using `ScalikeJdbc`
- `implicit val dateTimeJsReader = JodaReads.jodaDateReads("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`
- `implicit val dateTimeJsReader = JodaReads.jodaDateReads("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`

  These are `Joda` `DateTime` *read-write converters* (used by `ScalaJson`) for the `Joda` `DateTime` parameter of `case class`
- `implicit val reads = Json.reads[Table]`
- `implicit val writes = Json.writes[Table]`

  These are *read-write converters* for the given `case class`

---

Finally, here's the code-snippet for reading data of this case class from Json file

```
val tableOpt: Option[Table] = try {
  val rawJsonString: String = Source.fromFile("path/to/file/fileName.json").mkString
  Some(Json.parse(rawJsonString).as[Table])
} catch {
  case ex: Throwable =>
    println(s"Exception while reading Json file: '$ex'")
    None
}
```

---

One final piece of advice for *noobs* like me: Unless you are comfortable with `ScalaJson` (and `JSON` parsing, in general), avoid using the `Json.parse(jsonString).asOpt[T]` method (the above snippet uses `.as[T]` method) in order to overcome subtle mistakes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48745565/jsonparseexception-unexpected-character-code-58).

---

**EDIT-1**

> Does ScalikeJdbc support parsing Enum values like ScalaJson?

Getting `Enum.Value` really has nothing to do with `ScalikeJdbc`: once you have a `String`, how difficult is it to convert to `Enum.Value`?

Here's a small example:

```
// Enum
object CloudProvider extends Enumeration {

  val AWS: Value = Value("aws")
  val MicrosoftAzure: Value = Value("microsoft-azure")
  val GoogleCloud: Value = Value("google-cloud")
}

// Case Class
case class SiteInfo(website: String, provider: CloudProvider.Value)

// Mapper method
def mapResult(rs: WrappedResultSet): SiteInfo = {
  val website: String = rs.string("website")
  val provider: CloudProvider.Value = CloudProvider.values.
    find(_.toString == rs.string("provider")).
    getOrElse(CloudProvider.AWS)

  SiteInfo(website, provider)
}
```

It's difficult to understand why I couldn't see the answer when it was right there in front of me: (`mapResult` method)

---

> ..in general, is it a good idea to use Enums at all..

**Yes, Absolutely**

The entire point of having an `Enum` type is to restrict the range of values a variable can take. I can't see an easier way to enforce such rules other than an `Enum`.

Also once you have the sufficient know-how of language / library that your'e using (I didn't know much `Scala` & `ScalikeJdbc` at that time), there's absolutely no overhead (from coding perspective) for using `Enum`; in fact they make code much clearer. Needless to say even from performance perspective, using `Enum`s is far better that using `String`.