# JsonParseException: Unexpected character (':' (code 58))

Tags: json, scala, parsing, playframework

While trying to learn JSON-*parsing* in `Scala` using `Play Framework`'s [ScalaJson](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson) through [**`JSON` automated mapping**](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJsonAutomated) using `case class`es, I'm getting the said error.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: 
"column" : {
    "name" : "column_name"
}; line: 2, column: 11]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(scalaPlayJson.sc:1577)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(scalaPlayJson.sc:529)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(scalaPlayJson.sc:458)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddValue(scalaPlayJson.sc:1620)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(scalaPlayJson.sc:685)
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(scalaPlayJson.sc:175)
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(scalaPlayJson.sc:124)
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JsValueDeserializer.deserialize(scalaPlayJson.sc:119)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(scalaPlayJson.sc:3704)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(scalaPlayJson.sc:2001)
    at play.api.libs.json.jackson.JacksonJson$.parseJsValue(scalaPlayJson.sc:231)
    at play.api.libs.json.StaticBinding$.parseJsValue(scalaPlayJson.sc:12)
    at play.api.libs.json.Json$.parse(scalaPlayJson.sc:167)
    at #worksheet#.#worksheet#(scalaPlayJson.sc:50)
```

The input in question is the *simplest* `JSON` one could think of [file: `column.json`]

```
{
  "column": {
    "name": "column_name"
  }
}
```

I'm using the following code to parse the given Json file.

```
case class Column(
                   tableId:      Option[Int]     = None,
                   id:           Option[Int]     = None,
                   name:         String,
                   shouldCopy:   Option[Boolean] = None,
                   dataType:     Option[String]  = None,
                   defaultValue: Option[String]  = None
                 ) {
  def showColumnInfo: Unit = println(s"Name = $name")
}

object Column {
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Column]
  implicit val writes = Json.writes[Column]
  implicit val format = Json.format[Column]
}

Json.parse(Source.fromFile(s"$path/column.json").mkString("")).
  asOpt[Column].
  getOrElse(Column(name = "Could not read")).
  showColumnInfo
```

---

Things that I've tried without success:

- Change the key `"column"` to `"Column"` in `JSON` (capitalize 'C' to match `case class`'s name)
- Provide the above `JSON` as `String` instead of reading it from file

---

My questions are:

- What's causing the error?
- Where can I find list of all `JsonParseException` **error codes** with their meanings?

---

Framework versions:

- `Scala` **v2.11.11**
- `Play-Json` **v2.6.6** [`SBT`: `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.6"`]
- `SBT` **v1.0.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my input `JSON` was wrong (it was a *valid* `JSON`, but incorrect as per provided `case class`). I had wrapped it inside an **extra pair of braces** `{}` where it should have been

```
{
  "name": "column_name"
}
```

---

For anyone starting with `Play-JSON`, I would suggest them to use `JsValue.as[T]` instead of `JsValue.asOpt[T]` because the latter *doesn't report any errors* and you'll keep banging your head (I wasted over 5 hours **`:-(`**). The [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaJson#Using-JsValue.as/asOpt) warn about it in advance:

> Although the asOpt method is safer, any error information is lost.

Comment: I still haven't not found any *link* that explains all different `error codes` of `JsonParseException`; will share my finding here whenever i come across it